# TERM environment variable not set when running shell script using automator (MAC)

Tags: mac, shell-script, xterm, automator, unmount

In using mac sonoma. I tried to run my shell script via Automator app. There's a 'diskutil umount' command in the script that will give me this error :

```
TERM environment variable not set.
Usage:   diskutil u[n]mount [force] MountPoint|DiskIdentifier|DeviceNode
```

I tried to do any of these but no luck :

```
export TERM=xterm-color
export TERM=xterm
```

If i run my script on the terminal , then It works perfectly. Only via automator I will got that error.

When running on terminal, I will be asked for password for that diskutil-unmount command via standard input. Does it have something to do with this password that I have to save it the env var? i'm not sure.

Does anyone know how to solve it?

Comment: I have not seen the script you're using, but try using the full path to `diskutil` and see if that makes any difference. Regarding the issue otherwise, I found: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/253681933?sortBy=best, https://discussions.apple.com/thread/928729?sortBy=best, and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48385156/trying-to-use-expect-in-mac-script for further reading in case anything there helps resolve or better understand what going on here.